# VDM++ clock time

Tags: clock, vdm++

I implemented a random number generator in vdm++. But I wanted to the seed to be the clock time from the computer. Does anyone know if there is a equivalent vdm++ function to c++ function `time(NULL)`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't exist any build-in lib to get the system time like `time(NULL)` but it is easy to create such a function in Java and link it to your model if you are using the Overture IDE for VDM.

The Overture User Guide has a section about this: [14.1 Defining Your Own Java Libraries to be used from Overture.](http://overture.sourceforge.net/docs/OvertureIDEUserGuide.pdf)

You have to create a jar file with a java class that gives you the system time like this:

```
public class SystemTime
{
    public static Value time()
    {
        return new RealValue(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

And its VDM counterpart:

```
class SystemTime

operations
public static time : () ==> real
time() == is not yet specified;

end SystemTime
```

Then place the jar and vdm file inside the project like this:
Project root/
  lib/
    systemtime.jar
    systemtime.vdmpp

Now you can use the VDM operation SystemTime`time() to get the system time.